# Inverse Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in F^{n*n}$ a inverse matrix and $B\in F^{n*n}$ a none inverse matrix

We can say that because A is row equivilate to $I_n$$ \implies $  $AB$ is none inverse matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, then $\det A \neq 0$ and if $B$ is non-invertible, then $\det B = 0$. But $\det AB = \det A \det B = \alpha \cdot 0 = 0$ for some $\alpha \neq 0$, so $AB$ is non-invertible.